# Python JSON encoding issues

Tags: python, json, encoding

I need to parse downloaded JSON file

[url](http://www.sreality.cz/api/cs/v1/estates/1647755356) of the file

I get unicode:

```
{u'type': u'string', u'name': u'Podla\u017e\xed', u'value': u'2. podla\u017e\xed'}
```

and I need to convert:

**\u017e** to **ž**

**\xed** to **í**

and so on...

How I can do it?

Comment: You are seeing a technical representation of the data as dictionary with escape sequences in the strings. That is normal if you print a dictionary. If you print the value individually they will be normal text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with unicode you have to make sure to decode your input correctly before you use it in your program and encode it back to `UTF-8` when serializing it to bytes. It seems that you handled the former already, so you can use the dictionary as it is.

When you want to save you dict as json again, you have to specify the correct encoding and serialize it to `UTF-8`.

```
import json
from io import open

with open('some_file.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(some_dict, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try open using code.
reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html

sample code.

```
import codecs
fileObj = codecs.open( "someFile", "r", "utf-8" )
u = fileObj.read()
```